# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type of structure in structure of assignment for the member

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I encountered a problem about pointer and structure.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
```

Define two structure, sub term and major term.

```
typedef struct{
    int sub_id;
    int sub_data;
    struct sub_term *next_term;
}sub_term;

typedef struct{
    char name[10];
    struct sub_term *init_term;
    struct sub_term *current_term;
}major_term;
```

I want to create a major term that contains sub term.

```
int main(void){

major_term *Test_1;
Test_1 = (major_term *)malloc(sizeof(major_term));

Test_1->init_term = (sub_term *)malloc(sizeof(sub_term));   
Test_1->current_term = Test_1->init_term;

printf("Sub term 1 id : ");
```

However, compiler notices me that "[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in this line.

```
scanf("%d",&Test_1->current_term->sub_id);
```

I am new to C language and not sure the reason. 
Thank you for your recommend that makes my code better !

```
printf("Sub term 1 id : ",Test_1->current_term->sub_id);
printf("Sub term 1 data: ");
scanf("%d",&Test_1->current_term->sub_data);
printf("Sub term 1 data : ",Test_1->current_term->sub_data);    

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the names for the structures, not just typedefs:

```
typedef struct sub_term{
//             ^^^^^^^^
    int sub_id;
    int sub_data;
    struct sub_term *next_term;
}sub_term;

typedef struct major_term{
//             ^^^^^^^^^^
    char name[10];
    struct sub_term *init_term;
    struct sub_term *current_term;
}major_term;
```

Defining type names with `typedef` like this

```
typedef struct {} MyType;
```

does not define the structure with name `MyType`. Instead, it defines the name `MyType` as an alias of an unnamed struct.

Structure names and general type names are in two separate namespaces in C, so `struct MyType` is different from `MyType`, and they don't interfere with each other.

When you declare a structure without defining it (i.e., providing the content of the structure), the structure is an incomplete type. In your code, you defined pointers to `struct sub_term` but you didn't define that structure (note again: `typedef`-ing does not give names to structures - it defines aliases for your unnamed structures), so the compiler complains about "incomlete types".